# How does return type in data class work in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin

So I have this `Result` class,

```
sealed class Result<S, F> {
    data class Success<S, F>(val value: S) : Result<S, F>()
    data class Failure<S, F>(val value: F) : Result<S, F>()
}
```

When I do `Result.Success("Success")` the returned value is `Success(value=Success)`. But `Success<S, F>(val value: S)` return type is `Result<S,F>()`.

Then how come `Result.Success("Success")` returns `Success(value=Success)`? Shouldn't it return the instance of `Result`?

I took this code from https://medium.com/@KaneCheshire/recreating-swifts-result-type-in-kotlin-f0a065fa6af1

Comment: It _does_ return an instance of `Result`, because `Result.Success` is a subclass of `Result`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You might have misunderstood what `: Result<S, F>()` means in these lines:

```
data class Success<S, F>(val value: S) : Result<S, F>()
data class Failure<S, F>(val value: F) : Result<S, F>()
```

You might have confused this with how return types of methods and functions are declared:

```
fun thisReturnsAnInt() : Int = 1
//                       ^^^
```

But these are totally different syntaxes. Notice how there is a pair parentheses after `Result<S, F>`. You don't normally see those in a return type, do you? `Result<S, F>()` *does not denote a return type*. It declares the [*base class*](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/inheritance.html) of `Success` (and `Failure`, in the second line) and describes how the base class should be initialised when `Success`/`Failure` is initialised - by passing no parameters to the base class constructor (hence the empty parentheses).

Let's take a step back for a moment and think about what we are actually doing in `data class Success<S, F>(val value: S)`. We are declaring a class called `Success`, and we are declaring that its primary [constructor](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/classes.html#constructors) has a parameter of type `S`. Since we are declaring a *constructor* here, it doesn't make sense to also write its return type with `: SomeType`. We've already stated it! It's `Success<S, F>`!

Answer (score -1):

First, let's recap the definition of `Kotlin Sealed Class` ([Read more about it here](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/sealed-classes.html))

> Sealed classes and interfaces represent restricted class hierarchies that provide more control over inheritance. All subclasses of a sealed class are known at compile time. No other subclasses may appear after a module with the sealed class is compiled. For example, third-party clients can't extend your sealed class in their code. Thus, each instance of a sealed class has a type from a limited set that is known when this class is compiled.

So by definition, the members of each `Sealed Class` **inherit** the properties of the `Sealed Class`. Inheritance is what makes `Sealed Class` very powerful and allows us to uses classes like `enums`.

Considering that you have understood the `Inheritance` part of `Sealed Class`, let us move on to the very exact problem you are encountering: **Kotlin Syntax**

Consider this code below :

```
class A {
    class B {
       
    }
}
```

Given the code above, how would you instantiate `Class B`? You would instantiate it like this:

```
fun instantiateB() {
    A.B()
    //And not B()
}
```

This is because `B` is an `inner class` of `A`. So you have to explicitly state `A`. See your given `Result` Sealed class, do you see how `Success` and `Failure` are an `inner class` of Sealed class `Result`? This is why you are getting `Result.Success("Success")`.

However, if you do not like `inner classes`, you could refactor the given code to remove `inner classes`:

```
sealed class Result<S, F> //notice no bracket?
data class Success<S, F>(val value: S) : Result<S, F>()
data class Failure<S, F>(val value: F) : Result<S, F>()
//Now you could do this, Success<Int, String>(1) <-- No Result. infront
```

This way, you still have all the functionalities of a `Sealed Class` without having `inner class` properties.

Let me know if you have any questions.